# paddleOCR Installation error, Failed building wheel for faiss-cpu

Tags: python, faiss, paddle

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for faiss-cpu
Failed to build faiss-cpu
ERROR: Could not build wheels for faiss-cpu, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am trying to install paddle ocr for text extraction using following command 1) `pip install paddlepaddle` 2) `pip install paddleocr` 3) `pip install paddleclas`
I am getting the errors while installing the last command
How can i resolve the errors

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install pyproject-toml`

Answer (score 0):

The Error that i encounter because i used the python version 3.11.5, paddle OCR works only for python version 3.9 or bellow that, I used the Python version 3.8 in a conda environment the issue was resolved.